# Gives me a complex solution

Tags: differential-equations, complex

```
A := DSolve[{D[((It - Ir) * x / L + Ir) * w''[x], {x, 2}] - p/Y, 
w[x] == 0, w'[0] == 0, w''[L] == M0/(Y*Ir), w'''[L] == -P/(Y*Ir)}, 
w[x], x]
```

I want a real solution to this. Am I making a mistake in defining the boundary conditions of the problem?

I am unable to yield the required solution.

Comment: Make sure you post the *actual* code you used, or at least that the code you post here does what you claim it does.

Comment: @Szabolcs I have posted the original code that I have used to solve the differential equation. The output is a complex output while there exists a real solution to this equation which I have evaluated using the hand. I require the solution to be in real terms.

Comment: No, you have not. Copy the code back to a notebook and evaluate it. Does it do what you claim? The DSolve syntax isn't even correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if that's what you wanted, but writing:

```
sol = DSolve[{D[Y((It - Ir)x/L + Ir)w''[x], {x, 2}] == q,
              w[0] == 0,
              w'[0] == 0,
              w''[L] == -m/(Y It),
              w'''[L] == -f/(Y It) + m/(Y It^2)(It - Ir)/L},
              w[x], 
              x][[1, 1, 2]] /. Log[expr_] :> Log[Abs[expr]] // Simplify
```

or, in a much more intuitive way, by writing:

```
sol = DSolve[{Y((It - Ir)x/L + Ir)w''[x] == -(m - f(L - x) - q(L - x)^2/2),
              w[0] == 0,
              w'[0] == 0},
              w[x], 
              x][[1, 1, 2]] /. Log[expr_] :> Log[Abs[expr]] // Simplify
```

I get:

> (1/(12 (Ir - It)^4 Y))L ((Ir - It) x (-Ir^2 (12 m + q x (-3 L + x)) + 6 f (Ir - It) (Ir x - It (2 L + x)) + Ir It (24 m + q x (-9 L + 2 x)) + It^2 (-12 m + q (6 L^2 + 6 L x - x^2))) + 6 (2 f (Ir - It) It L + 2 Ir^2 m - 4 Ir It m + It^2 (2 m - L^2 q)) (Ir (L - x) + It x) Log[Abs[Ir L]] - 6 (2 f (Ir - It) It L + 2 Ir^2 m - 4 Ir It m + It^2 (2 m - L^2 q)) (Ir (L - x) + It x) Log[Abs[Ir L - Ir x + It x]])

which seems to me a good result.

In particular, writing:

```
nsol = sol /. {It -> 10, 
               Ir -> 5, 
               Y -> 2*10^11, 
               L -> 3, 
               f -> 1, 
               m -> 3/10,
               q -> 1/2} // FullSimplify
```

I get:

> (x (-1764 + 5 (-39 + x) x) + 1764 (3 + x) Log[1/3 Abs[3 + x]])/40000000000000

which is the same that is obtained by initially defining these parameters.

Specifically, writing:

```
nsol // N // Chop

Plot[nsol, {x, 0, 3}, 
     AxesLabel -> {"x [m]", "w [m]"}, 
     ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, "Reverse"}]
```

I get:

> 0
>
> [image]

that experience suggests that substituted numbers are not physically significant. Check the units of measurement, surely the catch is there (I think it is the integration of the elastic line to the Euler-Bernoulli in the case in which the beam has a variable section).

Answer (score 1):

```
It = 10;
Ir = 5;
Y = 2*10^11;
L = 3;
P = 1;
p = 0.5;
M0 = 0.3;
```

`A = DSolve[{D[((It - Ir) x/L + Ir) w''[x], {x, 2}] == -p/Y, w[0] == 0,
      w'[0] == 0, w''[L] == M0/(Y *Ir), w'''[L] == -P/(Y *Ir)}, w[x], 
    x] /. Log[expr_] :> Log[Abs[expr]] // FullSimplify`

Gives me this result:

```
{{w[x] -> 
  x^2 (5.25*10^-13 - 1.25*10^-13 x + 
  3.*10^-12 HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1., 
     1.}, {3.}, -0.333333 x])}}
```

which is not in real terms.

Comment: If this was meant as an addition to the question, then please edit the question. Do not post it as an answer. See the [Tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) on how StackExchange works.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

It = 10;
Ir = 5;
Y = 2*10^11;
L = 3;
P = 1;
p = 1/2;
M0 = 3/10;

eqns = {D[((It - Ir) x/L + Ir) w''[x], {x, 2}] == -p/Y, w[0] == 0, 
  w'[0] == 0, w''[L] == M0/(Y*Ir), w'''[L] == -P/(Y*Ir)};

A = DSolve[eqns, w, x][[1]] // FullSimplify

(* {w -> Function[{x}, (-360 x + 21 x^2 - 5 x^3 - 1080 Log[3] - 
     360 x Log[3] + 1080 Log[3 + x] + 
       360 x Log[3 + x])/40000000000000]} *)
```

Verifying the solution,

```
And @@ (eqns /. A // Simplify)

(* True *)
```

To find the domain for which `w[x]` is real use [`FunctionDomain`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionDomain.html)

```
FunctionDomain[w[x] /. A, x]

(* x > -3 *)
```

For that domain, the function simplifies to

```
w[x_] = w[x] /. A // FullSimplify[#, x > -3] &

(* (x (-360 + (21 - 5 x) x) + 360 (3 + x) Log[(3 + x)/3])/40000000000000 *)

Plot[w[x], {x, -3, 12}]
```

[image]